How does path-lookup understand concurrent changes on inode in the Linux kernel?
In the Linux kernel pathname lookup can be done in either RCU or REF mode. The documentation says that:
No ``inode->i_rwsem`` or even ``rename_lock``
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

<...>. If some other thread does
take ``i_rwsem`` and modifies the directory in a way that RCU-walk needs
to notice, the result will be either that RCU-walk fails to find the
dentry that it is looking for, or it will find a dentry which
``read_seqretry()`` won't validate.  In either case it will drop down to
REF-walk mode which can take whatever locks are needed.

From chmod source code:
int chmod_common(const struct path *path, umode_t mode)
{
    ...
    inode_lock(inode);
    error = security_path_chmod(path, mode);
    if (error)
        goto out_unlock;
    newattrs.ia_mode = (mode & S_IALLUGO) | (inode->i_mode & ~S_IALLUGO);
    newattrs.ia_valid = ATTR_MODE | ATTR_CTIME;
    error = notify_change(mnt_idmap(path->mnt), path->dentry,
                  &newattrs, &delegated_inode);
out_unlock:
    inode_unlock(inode);
    ...
}

it does take inode->i_rwsem by calling inode_{lock|unlock}, so if one thread was doing chmod and another was performing lookup (it first must try RCU mode, let's say that dentry is already cached). To be able to fall back to REF mode and use locks or drop to filesystem specific code it needs to invalidate dentry by calling d_invalidate (I'm not sure in this part, maybe there are other mechanism to do so), but in case of chmod it will call fsnotify_dentry, but it doesn't seem to invalidate or to remove the dentry from the dcache (I can be wrong here).
So, how exactly does chmod notify lookup that inode has been changed?

In general, it doesn't matter if the thread doing the lookup during the chmod sees the version of the inode with the old mode bits or the new mode bits. It doesn't matter which one got there first because the other one could have got there first.

@IanAbbott, what if the first thread is doing a lookup on a directory and has already checked the permissions for this directory, meanwhile another thread has changed permissions exactly on that directory, but the first thread has already checked them and got to lower level directory (the first thread has seen that the permissions are OK)?

@IanAbbott, it seems that you're right, but I can't understand the reason why it doesn't matter if e.g. permissions for root directory has been changed meanwhile another thread almost done lookup of much deeper directory, how it is handled

Moreover, in open_last_lookups it can take i_rwsem https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.10.8/source/fs/namei.c#L3573), but only if RCU-walk failed again (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.10.8/source/fs/namei.c#L3542), but there will be no permissions check, so it's a bit weird, so either seqcount must fail or there must be no such dentry in the dcache, as far as I understood
